# Newsstand kit and providing multiple magazines/newspapers in one application

Tags: ios

So basically my questions is: Can newsstand kit be used in one single app for several different magazine subscriptions? From the wwdc 504 session it doesn't really appear that this is true. In my understanding it appears that a magazine/newspaper subscription is coupled with 1 app. For instance the UIApplication setNewsstandIconImage only has a single UIImage parameter, so I can only deduce from this that one and only one newstand image can exist or rather be active for a single application. Am I missing something here, can someone confirm or deny my suspicions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`setNesstandIconImage` sets the icon of your app. You app only ever has one icon, so it doesn't make sense to set it to multiple images. This, in an of itself, does not limit Newsstand to being used for one publication only. Just set the icon to whatever the newest issue is, regardless of publication.

While subscriptions are coupled to an app (you can only purchase a subscription from the app it's linked to), there is no limit to the number of subscriptions your app can offer. And what you do with those subscriptions is completely up to you. The only thing Apple will tell you is the subscription ID, if it's active, and when it was purchased (and a few other meta). What you download/enable/unlock based on that information is up to you.

So there's no technical reason your single app couldn't offer subscriptions to Time, Newssweek, and the Wall Street Journal (and maybe a fourth subscription to all three for a reduced price).

There may be usability or design reasons you wouldn't want to do that. But technically the API supports it.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of what you said, but your last sentence precisely describes why it isn't suitable for my purposes. Thanks for the input though, always appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the way Newsstand is today managed and displayed by iOS makes it more suitable for one-app-one-magazine apps than multi-magazine ones.
Technically making a multiple magazine Newsstand app is not impossible. All in all Apple limits pushes to one per day, but it doesn't mean that in your push notification you can add a payload that refers to multiple issues to be downloaded at a time: as far your app is moved in the background from the push notification you will be able, based on payload data, to schedule as many downloads as you want (they will be serially queued in the NK download queue).
Of course the single UIImage parameters is a real limitation. Normally you should add on it the latest downloaded issue: intact the rule is that the cover must be updated once the magazine is ready in the device, so typically you will update the cover after magazine download and installation. Eventually  for a multiple-magazine app you can consider a generic cover and then keep the user informed of the latest download thanks to the badge in the icon.

Anyway I agree with you: the user experience is improved by Newsstand mainly on single-magazine apps.